# Capture Chat File Transfer Request

Tags: liveagent, chat, livechattranscript

Saleforce has a Chat (Live Agent) feature to request files from a visitor: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.live_agent_transfer_files.htm&type=5

[image]

Is it possible to immediately get ID of uploaded file (testFile.png on the screenshot) linked to the current chat?

It lands in Salesforce as a Content Document and appears in the standard conversation component.

[image]

Comment: What is your usecase for fetching the Id of uploaded file immediately?

Comment: we have a custom conversation component that should display exactly same messages as the standard one.

Comment: You could listen for the chat event [File Transfer Succeeded](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.live_agent_transcript_events.htm&type=5) and query the most recent file linked with the record.

Comment: @Swetha, thanks, I tried that, but Live chat transcript events are available only at the end of the chat https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000380912&type=1

Comment: and there is no such file transfer event among  snapins chat events https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_chat_events.htm

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the concerned Salesforce product team internally on your ask and found that this is currently a platform limitation.

It is on Salesforce's roadmap to bring these events into Messaging for In-App and Web(MIAW) and make them proper events.

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort, Swetha!

Comment: Are there any updates regarding this?